# How do I use Gio library in Vala?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I'm building a Gtk application in Vala and would like to use the [Gio](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/index.html) library and more specifically the [g_app_info_get_all()](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/type_func.AppInfo.get_all.html) function. I am able to achieve this in C as follows:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib/gi18n.h>
#include <gio/gdesktopappinfo.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ...

  GDesktopAppInfo *app_info;
  GList *app_list, *l;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  ...

  app_list = g_app_info_get_all();
  
  ...

}
```

How do I achieve the same in Vala?

ChatGPT suggested me to use Gio.AppInfo.get_all()
and even though
`pkg-config --modversion gio-2.0` returns 2.74.3 but `using Gio;` throws an error saying the namespace 'Gio' could not be found even when I'm compiling with --pkg gio-2.0 flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace is `GLib`, this is shown as `{} Glib` in [Valadoc](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.AppInfo.get_all.html). The `GLib` namespace is used by default, so the following will work:

```vala
void main () {
    var result = AppInfo.get_all ();
    foreach (var app in result) {
        print (@"$(app.get_display_name())\n");
    }
}
```

Compile with:

```
valac example.vala --pkg gio-2.0
```